# google.payments.inapp.getPurchases doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm creating chrome extension and using inapp purchase in it. 
According Google [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/payments-iap) I included [buy.js](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/samples/managed-in-app-payments/scripts/buy.js) and using it's methods. 
**getSkuDetails** and **buy** works fine, but **getPurchases** gives me next error - **INVALID_RESPONSE_ERROR**. 
I switched to another account (same browser) and **getPurchases** starts working.

Here is my code:

```js
class Monetization {
  getItemsList() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      google.payments.inapp.getSkuDetails({
        'parameters': {'env': 'prod'},
        'success': (response) => {
          resolve(response);
        },
        'failure': (error) => {
          reject(error);
        }
      });
    });
  }
  
  getPurchasedItems() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      google.payments.inapp.getPurchases({
        'parameters': {'env': 'prod'},
        'success': (response) => {
          resolve(response);
        },
        'failure': (error) => {
          reject(error);
        }
      });
    });
  }
  
  buyItem(sku) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      google.payments.inapp.buy({
        'parameters': {'env': 'prod'},
        'sku': sku,
        'success': (response) => {
          resolve(response);
        },
        'failure': (error) => {
          reject(error);
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Both accounts has valid cards, any idea what can be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Could this be related to the fact that as a publisher of the extension you're not allowed to purchase your own extensions or in-app purchases. See [In-App purchases not working in chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39923575/in-app-purchases-not-working-in-chrome-extension)